# Idea of compare weighted probability

Tags: probability, implicit-function-theorem

I'm stuck with how to deal with the following expected probability expression.

Assume $F(.)$ is a CDF function and $q\in[0,1]$. 
$$
P(x;q) = q\cdot F(\alpha(x;q)\cdot x)+(1-q)\cdot F((1+\alpha(x;q))\cdot x)
$$ 
where $$\alpha(x;q) = \frac{q\cdot F(\alpha(x;q)\cdot x)}{P(x;q)}\in [0,1]$$

**My question:**  I would like to compare $P(x;q)$ and $F(x)$.

I've tried using implicit function theorem but things suddenly go messy... All I know so far is that
$$P(x;1)=P(x;0)=F(x)$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Is $\alpha$ a given constant, in which case what's the relevance of the second displayed equation, or (as the second equation suggests) a function of $x$?

Comment: @kimchilover $\alpha$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  So your equation boils down to $\alpha(x)/(1-\alpha(x))=(q/(1-q) )F(\alpha(x)x)/F((1+\alpha(x))x)$, right?

Comment: @kimchilover Exactly. And you can assume $x>0$. So I have shifted terms in the CDF. $\alpha(x)x<x,(1+\alpha(x))x>x$.